# From two tables with a relationship I want to use SELECT statement to retrieve data from database and display them in jTable

Tags: java

I have two tables with a relationship. I want to use SELECT statement to retrieve data from database and display them in jTable. I am trying this

```
string sql “select customer.customer_id,bill.amount from customer inner join bill on customer.customer_id = bill.customer_id where customer.customer_id = ?”;
```

But when user supply customer id it generate an error "index out of range".

Comment: You might not have that customer id in table or customer might not have bill. Better try left join instead of inner join.

Comment: Thanks SMA, but my tables contain that columns which i specified in a query.

Comment: You have a Java exception, a question with only Java tagged, but no Java code. How about you shared that?

Comment: JavaCode for that question is

Comment: JavaCode for that question is pst=con.preparestatement(sql); pst.setString(1,customer_id.getText()); rs = pst.executeQuery(sql); jtabel1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs))

Comment: @mulisainnocent Edit your question with your comment to include the JavaCode.

Comment: @mulisainnocent Please edit your question to include the complete error message you get. Also edit your question to include the full source code you have.

Comment: thanks all..i have already get a solution.thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
String customerId = text_customerid.getText();
try{
  `con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cafesystem","root","root");`

  `String sql ="SELECT customer.CUSTOMER_ID, bill.AMOUNT from customer 
              INNER JOIN bill on customer.CUSTOMER_ID = bill.CUSTOMER_ID 
              WHERE customer.customer_id ='"+customerId+"'";

  pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
  rs  = pst.executeQuery(sql);

  jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));`
} catch(SQLException ex) { ... }
```